# Disable and enable view android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-custom-view

My target is to draw free shapes above google map v2, so I created an app to draw free shapes by finger movement in a custom view and putted this view above the map fragment in the layout.xml and made the view background to be transparent. 
and now I can draw free shapes well but the problem now is that I can't control map or do zooming or dragging in it.

Is there are any way to make me control both of them, for example a button to covert the control from map fragment to view of drawing and vise versa ?
or to turn on/off the view of drawing?

this is my code

DrawerView.java

```
public class DrawerView extends View {

public Paint paint = new Paint();
public Path path = new Path();
public Path circlePath = new Path();

private int lineCol;


public LayoutParams params;


public DrawerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);

    //get the attributes specified in attrs.xml using the name we included
    TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
            R.styleable.LineView, 0, 0);

    try {
        //get the text and colors specified using the names in attrs.xml

        lineCol = a.getInteger(R.styleable.LineView_lineColor, 0);//0 is default

    } finally {
        a.recycle();
    }

    //paint object for drawing in onDraw
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(lineCol);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(4f);

}   

public void onButtonPress(){
    // resets the screen
    path.reset();

    // Calls the onDraw() method
    postInvalidate();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    //canvas.drawPath(circlePath, circlePaint);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    // Gives you x and y coordinates on the Event.
    float pointX = event.getX();
    float pointY = event.getY();

    // Checks for the event that occurs
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        path.moveTo(pointX, pointY);

        return true;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        path.lineTo(pointX, pointY);
        circlePath.reset();

        circlePath.addCircle(pointX, pointY, 30, Path.Direction.CW);
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        circlePath.reset();

        break;
    default:
        return false;
    }

    postInvalidate();
    return true;
}
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
implements OnMapClickListener, OnMapLongClickListener, OnMarkerDragListener{

final int RQS_GooglePlayServices = 1;
private GoogleMap myMap;

Location myLocation;

boolean markerClicked;
PolygonOptions polygonOptions;
Polygon polygon;

Button plane;
Button tank;
Button ship;

DrawerView myView;
public Button btnReset;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     plane = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_plane);
     tank = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_tank);
     ship = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_ship);

    FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    MapFragment myMapFragment = (MapFragment)myFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    myMap = myMapFragment.getMap();

    myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

    myMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
    myMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
    myMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);


    plane.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                    new LatLng(0.00, 0.00)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.plane)).draggable(true));

        }
    });

    tank.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                    new LatLng(0.00, 0.00)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.tank)).draggable(true));

        }
    });

    ship.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                    new LatLng(0.00, 0.00)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.destroyer)).draggable(true));

        }
    });

    markerClicked = false;

    myView = (DrawerView)findViewById(R.id.custView);
    myView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    btnReset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clear);

    btnReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            myView.path.reset();
            myView.postInvalidate();

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_settings:
        String LicenseInfo = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo(
                getApplicationContext());
        AlertDialog.Builder LicenseDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        LicenseDialog.setTitle("Legal Notices");
        LicenseDialog.setMessage(LicenseInfo);
        LicenseDialog.show();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());

    if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                "isGooglePlayServicesAvailable SUCCESS", 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, RQS_GooglePlayServices);
    }

}

@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
    myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point));

    markerClicked = false;
}

@Override
public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {      
    markerClicked = false;
}

@Override
public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {
}

@Override
public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
}

@Override
public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {

}

  }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.dmeogooglemapv2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >


<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_tank"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"        
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/tank" /> 

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_plane"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"        
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/plane" /> 

   <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_ship"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"        
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/destroyer" /> 

   <Button
    android:id="@+id/clear"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Clear" />

   </LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.dmeogooglemapv2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"  >

    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>

    <com.example.dmeogooglemapv2.DrawerView
    android:id="@+id/custView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    custom:lineColor="#ff0099" />

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can switch between the receivers of touch events by returning `false` in your `onTouchEvent`, this should propagate event to the next view.

**UPD:** The code should be something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
if (!isTouchable) return false;
// your DrawerView logic
}
```

where `isTouchable` is a boolean variable which should be `false` is you don't want to draw on your view and `true` if you want to draw.

Comment: Could you show me how by the code? and will this make me control the map again?

Comment: Curious about UPD stand?

Comment: Why not just simply `return isTouchable;` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can enable or disable click on your drawing overlay:

```
findViewById(R.id.custView).setClickable(true/false);
```

While your drawing overlay is not clickable, you will be able to interact with the map.