# Draw polygon using onMarkerDrag google map v2

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to draw a free form lines over google map v2, so I'm trying to do this by listening to marker drag. I wrote the following code but it doesn't draw anything

```
@Override
public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {
    Integer markerId = markerMapHash.get(marker);
    // as I'm giving every marker a key by HashMap 
    if (markerId == 1) {
        System.out.println("this is the draw line marker: "+marker.getPosition());
        lineCordinates.add(marker.getPosition());
        // lineCordinates is an arrayList

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < lineCordinates.size(); i++) {
        myMap.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions()
        .add(lineCordinates.get(i))
        .strokeColor(Color.RED));
    }

}
```

Could anyone help me in this issue? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using polyline instead of polygon

```
 myMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
        .addAll(lineCordinates)
        .width(5)
        .color(Color.RED));
```